# Storing Temp. Data in ASP.NET Core (NopCommerce)

Tags: asp.net, caching, nopcommerce, tempdata

Dear StackOverflow community,

For a project of mine I need to store (Temporary) data somewhere else than a Database. Actually its a little more complicated. I have a checkout page in NopCommerce where users can select them delivery moment or even location for example pickup. This data has to be store temporary untill the user made the payment. Only then I will request the data and store in DB. So that later I can retrieve the data and display in my dashboard, So that I know when the package is scheduled to be shipped.

Requirements:

- Endurement: 12-24 Hours.
- Store as user specific data.
- Data has to be safed for quite a few sessions. Depends on the user. For example. If the user chooses a delivery moment but desides to look somewhere else before paying. This data has to be stored all those sessions.
- If possible serverside.

I have quite a few options following Microsoft:
[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Now I have tried storing data in Memory (Caching data) using 'MemoryCacheEntryOptions'. The problem is that its application wide. And its hard to maintain with hundreds of users.

Other option is **'Session state'**.
The problem is that this data only endures a single session. I need to hold the data for atleast 12 to 24 hours.

Then we have **'Temp Data'**. This seems like a promising option. Its great since it is kept until the is has been used/read. You even have 'Peek' and 'Keep' Methods to keep the data while peeking. Problem: It requires a controller. And requesting the data is a callback Method that doesnt require a Controller.

**'Query Strings'** Well its not much is it? This may be not user critical data BUT seems like query string isnt what Im looking for.

**'Hidden Fields'** Not really suitable either. It is therefore not form data.

**'HttpContext.Items'** Definetly not suitable. Data is only stored for single request.

**'Cache'** Way to hard to maintain user specific data.

So my question is. How do I save all this data temporary, if possible server side for a day atleast with hundreds of users at the same moment. And request the data later in a callback, to store it in DB until the order is shipped.

Comment: Why not a different database for temp data? But another option would be to just write a file to disk with a specific ID?

Comment: Probably not such a bad idea a temp database. I have given it a thought. But then I have to scheduled tasks that clears the DB data after x time. File to disk? Rather not.

Comment: Clearing a db table can be done with a job in the Agent

Comment: What do you mean with a job in de Agent?

Comment: SQL Server has an SQL Server Agent (not in Express). In there you can schedule stuff like backups, execute stored procedures etc.

Comment: Seems like a good solution Thanks for your input! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

NopCommerce exposes a class called GenericAttributeService in Nop.Services.Common. This allows you to store your custom attribute data, specific to each customer.

To use it, first inject the GenericAttributeService into your class (controller, service class, etc).

```
private readonly IGenericAttributeService _genericAttributeService;
public MyFancyController(IGenericAttributeService genericAttributeService)
{
   _genericAttributeService = genericAttributeService;
}
```

To save the data for current customer, use SaveAttribute and save an key-value pair you need:

```
 _genericAttributeService.SaveAttribute<string>(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, "MyKeyName", "Value to save for this customer")
 _genericAttributeService.SaveAttribute<int>(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, "My2ndKeyName", model.id)
```

To get the data use GetAttributesForEntity, where the entity is your key value.

```
var attribute = _genericAttributeService.GetAttributesForEntity(_workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id, "Customer").Where(x => x.Key == "MyKeyName").FirstOrDefault();
```

To delete the attribute use DeleteAttribute:

```
_genericAttributeService.DeleteAttribute(attribute);
```

Notice that we used _workContext which helps expose the current customer.
This already works well with other temp functionality already existing in the application, such as managing shopping carts, wish lists, etc, so browsing the source code for other examples can also be helpful.